# D3.js Line Graph - Adding Grid To Background and Making Line Crurve

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

Does anyone know how I would add a grid to the background of a d3 line graph I have made and does anyone know how I would make my line graph curve rather than be rather rigid like it is now. the code below is for the line graph and it all works with the data file I have I just need it to have a grid on the background and be curved rather than how it is now. I also need to have the y axis display a percent rather than a decimal
any help would be appreciated.

JS, CSS and HTML --

```js
    var margin = { top: 20 , right: 20, bottom: 30 , left: 40} ,
width= 960 - margin.left - margin.right ,
height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0]) ; //remember: up / down are flipped

var x = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([0, width]).padding([0.1]); //the last peramter adds padding

var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-10, 0])
  .html(function(event,d) {
    return "<strong>Frequency:</strong> <span style='color: rgba(223,222,79,255)'>" + d.frequency + "</span>";
  })

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.call(tip);

d3.csv("data/data.csv").then(function(data) {
    x.domain(data.map(function(d){return d.letter;}));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){return d.frequency;})]);
    // Remember to add all data dependant calls in here
    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(x); // Positions the Lables Under the xAxis

    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft().scale(y); // positions the lables on the left of the yAxis

    var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })

    x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));

    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);


  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Frequency");

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);


  svg.selectAll("circle")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "circle")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {return x (d.letter);})
      .attr("cy", function(d) {return y (d.frequency);})
      .attr("r", 4)

      .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
      .attr("height", function(d) {return height - y (d.frequency);})
      .on('mouseover', tip.show)
      .on('mouseout', tip.hide);

  svg.append("text")
      .attr("x", (width / 2))
      .attr("y", 0 + (margin.top / 2))
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text("Relative Frequence of Letters in the English Alphabet") ;
});
```

```css
    .bar {
  fill:rgba(55,125,34,255);
}
.bar:hover {
  fill: rgba(55,125,34,255);
}
.axis--x path {
  display: none;
}
.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke:  rgba(55,125,34,255);
  stroke-width: 3px;
}
.circle {
  fill: rgba(55,125,34,255);
}



.d3-tip {
    line-height: 1;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 12px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  }

  /* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */
.d3-tip:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 1;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    content: "\25BC";
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
  }

  /* Style northward tooltips differently */
.d3-tip.n:after {
    margin: -1px 0 0 0;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Demo</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mystyle.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg class="chart"></svg>
        <script type="text/javascript"src="js/d3/d3.js"></script>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/bumbeishvili/d3-tip-for-v6@4/d3-tip.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"src="js/myscript1.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add gridlines to an axis by using `axis.tickSize([size])` or  `axis.tickSizeInner([size])`.

Ex:

```
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(x).tickSize(.width);
```

As for the lines, you can make them curves by using the .curve method of the line, eg:

```
 var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
    .curve(d3.curveBasis)
```

Check these pages for the full reference:

- https://github.com/d3/d3-axis
- https://github.com/d3/d3-shape